# Python: better file I/0 using os.fork?

Tags: python, file-io, multiprocessing, shared-memory

My problem is quite simple: I have a 400MB file filled with 10,000,000 lines of data. I need to iterate over each line, do something, and remove the line from memory to avoid filling-up too much RAM.

Since my machine has several processor, my initial idea to optimize this process was to create two different processes. One would read the file several lines at a time and gradually fill a list (one element of the list being one line in the file). The other would have access to this same list and would pop() elements out of it and process them. This would effectively create a list that would grow from one side and shrink from the other.

In other words, this mechanism should implement a buffer that would constantly be populated with lines for the second process to crunch. But maybe this is no faster than using:

```
for line in open('/data/workfile', 'r'):
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but your algorithm appears to be I/O bound rather than CPU bound. That is, the amount of processing that needs to be done on each line is minimal, so your bottleneck is how fast the 400MB file can be read from disk. If this is indeed the case, don't expect much of a speed improvement for the time you'll be putting in.

Comment: Yes, my algorithm is definitely I/O bound. At the same time users are always impatient and anything I do will be called "too slow" by someone. That is the primary reason for me to start looking for something slightly more optimized than the built-in "for line in file".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably limited by the speed of your disk. Python already does buffering so reading it line by line is efficient.

Answer (score 4):

Your proposed `for line in open('/data/workfile', 'r'):` will use a generator, so the entire file will not be read into memory.  I'd go with that until it actually turns out to be too slow.

Comment: I agree.  The proposal would probably hurt performance by (1) spamming the processor data cache, and (2) thrashing the Python global interpreter lock.

Answer (score 1):

Probably before blind optimizing would be better to profile your existing code and see where the bottle neck really is.

Even if processing really is I/O bound adding couple threads to program could help a bit.

This will allow another thread to wait IO while another is processing the previously read data.

Answer (score 0):

The data structure you want to use is a Queue (it has the proper blocking mechanisms by example for concurrent writes), that is available in Multiprocessing module.

If you have no dependency between the processing of your data, you could MAP the line by line generator to a pool of processes with the functions in that module to multicore-enable the whole thing in a few lines.

See Also mapReduce approaches (it might be a little overkill however)